# EC2 instance best practice for Mongodb and App deployment

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, production-environment

I installed Mongodb in EC2 t2.small instance with [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/#manually-deploy-mongodb-on-ec2) guide. I don't know whether dedicate this instance for MonogoDB. or use this same instance for app deployment for production. Suggest me the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

The 'best practice' is to run the database server on its on instance; the even better 'best practice' is to run MongoDB on a cluster of instances to give you high availability.

That said, its perfectably acceptable, imo, to run the DB and your app on the same instance for small projects with low demands where cost is an important driver, although personally I would use at least a EC2 large instance if you are going to make your instance do double-duty in this manner.

Now that you know what is 'best', only you can determine how much 'best' you can afford.